# Get mixed in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table in postgresql include in countries and bird species column. I want to get what country has the most number of bird species.How can I do that? any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: please post your attempt at solving this

Comment: dear @vkp. Actualy. One of the way is to use select by any country column name and then count it's retrieved birds species. But there are so many countries and I really don't to do that for every countries. I'm looking for any suggestion to avoid that weariful way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank` to get all the countries with the highest number of species.

```
select country from 
(
select country, dense_rank() over(order by count(*) desc) as rnk
from yourtable
) t
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to solve this is using `group by` and `limit`/`fetch first 1 row only`:

```
select country, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by country
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Note:  in case multiple countries are tied, then this will only return one of them.